# Why is the current like this?

Tags: diodes, simulation

[image: Graph]

This is the current going out from the Vsin-source and below is the circuit I simulated.
[image: Circuit]

Could someone explain to me why the current looks like this?

Comment: Why don't you say what you expect it to look like?

Comment: Given that silicon diodes don't really turn on until the forward drop is about 0.6V. Your using a 0.2V amplitude so you're in the most non-linear section of the characteristic.

Comment: Theoretically, there is no current through D4, because the Voltage is always positive relative to GND? How do you get negative current?

Comment: @Naz Are you drunk? The AC source produces a negative voltage.

Comment: Increase the voltage significantly if you want to escape from the highly unlinear region where the forward voltage drop is not yet overcome.

Comment: @winny No, I did not drink )). But the negative terminal of V9 is grounded. I guess, I do not now how that source functions. Never mind, I see it now. The '+' terminal produces voltages below '-'.

Comment: @Naz Correct. More characters.

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out the **size of the current involved** - max +/- 240nA which, if the back of my envelope is correct, corresponds to a maximum 'drop' across the 1k resistor of about +/- 0.2mV. (or about 0.1%) If the Y axis was changed to voltage the picture would look very different - a sinusoidal wave with an extremely small compression.

Answer (score 2):

The current looks like it does because the diode is non-linear at the low voltage provided by the source.

It may be helpful to mention here the diode equation for a p-n junction:
$$
I=I_0(e^{V/\eta V_T}-1)
$$
where 
\$V\$ is voltage across the diode, \$I_0\$ is its reverse saturation current, \$V_T = kT/q\$ is the thermal voltage (about 26mV at room temp) and \$\eta\$ is approx 2 for silicon.

See also [Shockley_diode_equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The current thru diodes is a exponential function of the voltage across them.  A little change in voltage causes a large change in current.

The non-linear response of your circuit is due to this non-linear response of the diodes.  The peaks of the waveforms are higher because the current is more than linearly higher at higher voltage across the diodes.

Comment: Would you call it the reverse saturation current that is being displayed on the graph?

Comment: @Keil: No, I wouldn't.